# Remove numbers from beginning of string using regex

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to find the right regex to remove just the numbers from the beginning of a string

```
>from
8012 name last name 123 456
6952332 name last 213 5695

>into
name last name 123 456
name last 213 5695
```

this is not good cus its matching all

```
 @"[\d-]"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to anchor your pattern to the beginning of the string `^`

```
string pattern = @"^[0-9]+";   // or @"^\d+";
string source = "8012 name last name 123 456";
string newText  = Regex.Replace(source, pattern, "");
```